# keeping line break while sending email using php

Tags: php, email, sendmail, line-breaks

I am using below php code to send email after collecting user entered email ID (email-box) and content from a textarea(output_textarea) as message.

```
$to = $_REQUEST['email-box'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['output_textarea'];
$subject = 'form meta cli script';
$headers = 'From: info@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: me@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

But outlook is removing the line break and on top giving message `"Extra Line breaks in this message were removed"` How can I keep the line break in outlook?

Comment: Set content type text/plain

Comment: @DevZer0       added it, but still it removing the line

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287816

Comment: if the message is text/plain using, `\r\n` should work; if the message type is text\html, use `<p></p>` tags.

Comment: http://www.masternewmedia.org/newsletter_publishing/newsletter_formatting/remove_line_breaks_issue_Microsoft_Outlook_2003_when_publishing_text_newsletters_20051217.htm

Comment: and some possible solutions to try here http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?144973-Plain-text-email-line-breaks-not-working